# Call when clicked on tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm making a `UITableView` where you can click on a `tableviewcell` and this should trigger a phone call to a phone number in an array.

The phone numbers are listed in an array, and these are also shown in the `tableviewcell`.

```
_Number = @[@"100",
          @"101",
          @"070 245 245"];
```

I'm new at this and I don't know how to start with this, I already got my `tableviewcontroller` and tableviewcell classes which are working.

Gratz and thanks in advance

Comment: Check the delegate methods: `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`? Or is your issue how to make a call?

Comment: is your tableview listing all the phone numbers?

Comment: Please note that with variables the first letter of the variable should be lowercase letters not uppercase. So `_Number` should be `_number` in fact it should be more descriptive since it is a group of numbers so it should actually be `_numbers` note the lowercase and the extra `s`. Try best to stick to conventions then your code will much more readable in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can do following :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *phoneNumber = [Number objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSURL *phoneNumberURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",   phoneNumber]];

    if( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneNumberURL] )
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneNumberURL];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert!!!" message:@"Not able to make a phone call." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [errorAlert show];
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think will happen with your code if I am on iPod or iPad?

Comment: you should check if your device can make a call, with **canOpenUrl**

Comment: @Andy the purpose of the question is that what if a user was using an iPad or an iPod using this code as it is wouldn't work. Like pawan has state you need to check if the device that the app is running on is capable of actually making a phone call so if would be better to wrap the `openURL:` part of this code in an if statement to check `canOpenURL:`. Otherwise whilst this will not crash it will offer a very bad user experience.

Comment: @Popeye I think it's a little off the scope of the original question, which is btw is quite blurry.

Comment: @Andy I would disagree on both parts. It's not off scope and it's not blurry at all. What makes you think this is blurry?

Comment: @Popeye you should probably read at least first comment to this Q. Don't bother to answer, I don't think we should discuss it here anyway.

Comment: @Andy Re-reading the whole question it is perfectly clear what they are after, I don't get why you think this is blurry. When a user clicks on a UITableViewCell in a UITableView they want it to trigger a phone call to a number that is in an array. What is unclear about that? If you're going to leave a comment saying it's unclear you could at least say why, otherwise your comment is redundant.

Comment: @Popeye So the Q is how to make a call, how to implement UITableViewDelegate or how to extract number from array, or all of listed?

Comment: @Andy you are definitely reading into it far to much. Also if you read `"I already got my tableviewcontroller and tableviewcell classes which are working."` They already have the `UITableViewController` working so this says to me that the `UITableViewDelegate` is also working.

Comment: @Popeye ok, returning back to your suggestion, what's the matter if you wrap the openURL with obviously unsupported protocol (tel:) on iPod, I guess that's same as not wrapping it as no crash will happen. I would understand the suggestion to show alert view or something.

Comment: The purpose would be to handle it to make it a good user experience and not a shockingly bad one.

Comment: Hi all, I have edited my response. Thanks for your comments. I have overlooked to make a check with canOpenURL.